# Can someone tell me the way around my Tradingview code requirement?

Tags: pine-script

I want an alert when the price of a stock(say Tesla) is lower than the 50 day moving average and the 50 day moving average is in turn lower then the 200 day moving average.

Basically, two conditions needs to be true for the alert to trigger.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

With this script on your chart you'll be able to configure the alert you need. Blue dots appear when the alert would have triggered:

```
//@version=4
study("Alert on close < ma50 and ma50 < ma200", "", true)
ma50 = sma(close, 50)
ma200 = sma(close, 200)
cond = close < ma50 and ma50 < ma200
plotchar(cond, "cond", "•", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plot(ma50, "ma50")
plot(ma200, "ma200", color.purple)
alertcondition(cond)
```

[image]